# What's the meaning of "turn the needle on"

Tags: meaning, expressions

Here is the quotation, said by Audun Martinsen, the VP of Oilfield Service Analysis of Rystad, on December the 7th as a press statement.

> But OPEC production cuts will **turn the needle on** the FID [final investment decision] for many projects in shale and offshore, which will eventually generate more transparency on future activity and revenue,”

Is it the same as 'moving the needle'?

Comment: My first guess would be that it's a conflation of "turn the knob" and "move the needle".  Whether the conflation would be intentional or un, though, I can't say.  But another possibility is that it's referring to moving the needle on a compass.

Comment: Almost certainly, Martinsen (who is Norwegian but attended graduate school at the University of California, Berkeley) meant "move the needle." [His answers to four personal questions](http://www.rystadenergy.com/AboutUs/people) on the Rystad Energy website reveal a strong but imperfect grasp of English business jargon, idiomatic U.S. English, and English grammar. At various points he uses the phrase "add values" (instead of "add value"), mentions that he enjoys "being outdoor," and talks about "algorithms that is the basis for our databases." His use of "turn the needle" is his own invention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a one-off "malapropism" from a non-native speaker.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as @FumbleFingers has already noted in a comment, "it's about a one-off 'malapropism' from a non-native speaker."